# mysql_num_rows returning TRUE

Tags: php, mysql

$exist query have 0 rows.

```
$exist = mysql_query("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='$epSlug'") or die(mysql_error());

$num_exist = mysql_num_rows($exist) or die(mysql_error());

if(!$num_exist){
mysql_query.......
}
```

After my understanding, my second query should be running(inside if statement)?
Can someone confirm this? Because it does not run somehow and I removed the statement and it ran. I'm really confused even though I read the manual, I've been trying a lot now, if anyone sees what I'm doing wrong please point out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing..

if ($num_exist > 0) {
    mysql_query ... 
}

or conversely try if (!($num_exists === 0))

As others said.. you need to test for a number not a boolean

Good luck and hth!

Comment: It's actually if($num_exists === 0), otherwise it would if(TRUE). This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

! = not, your only running the if clause when  $num_exists returns boolean FALSE

Comment: in my case it should run, because there is no row?

Comment: var_dump($num_exist); what does it return? does the answer then leap out at you?